# Strategies for grouping polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis, aggregation

I'm looking for strategies to replicate the functionality available via ArcGIS' "[Aggregate Polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00700000000s000000)" tool. This is different from a straight dissolve on the polygons - the operation has to fill in gaps within a certain tolerance.

I'd be happy with a solution in either QGIS or PostGIS. I tried to work something out already with a convex hull but it doesn't quite get what I'm after so I'm at a loss. Any strategies you've come across?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something using either ST_ConvexHull or ST_ConcaveHull. Obviously, this is just a quick hack, but it might work in your circumstances.

Here's my original polygons:

[image]

Here's a union of the pairwise convex hulls for polys <= 500m apart:

[image]

```
select st_union(geom) as geom 
from (
  select st_convexhull(st_collect(a.geom, b.geom)) as geom 
  from polys a, polys b
  where st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 500) and a.gid<b.gid
) t;
```

Here's a union of the pairwise concave hulls with 0.5 for the argument:

[image]

```
select st_union(geom) as geom 
from (
  select st_concavehull(st_collect(a.geom, b.geom), 0.5) as geom 
  from polys a, polys b 
  where st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 500) and a.gid<b.gid
) t;
```

Things get weird if you enable holes in ST_ConcaveHull:

[image]